# Differentiation of$ f^{-1}(x)$, where $f(x)=e^{x-1}+x^3-4x^{-3}+10$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

if $f(x)=e^{x-1}+x^3-4x^{-3}+10$ then find $\frac{d(f^{-1}(x))}{dx}$ at $x=8$.....

(here $f^{-1}(x)$ means inverse of $f(x)$)

I was trying to solve this problem but was not able to find out the way ...but I think the following result can be helpful.....

$\frac{d(f^{-1}(x))}{dx}=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$

Comment: Use the chain rule

Comment: Please explain....

Answer (score 3):

$$f'(x) = e^{x - 1} + 3x^2 + 12 x^{-4}$$

Note that $f(1) = 1 + 1 - 4 + 10 = 8$, so $f^{-1}(8) = 1$. 
So 
$$\left. \frac{df^{-1}}{dx} \right|_{x = 8} = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(8))} = \frac{1}{f'(1)} = \frac{1}{16}.$$